# Set mime type OR run the native media player

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

My app allow the user to save video files wherever he/she wants so when using this video files inside the app I end up with something like this

```xml
<video src={`D:/folder1/.../folderN/filename.mkv`}>
    <track default src={`D:/folder1/.../folderN/filename-subs.srt`} kind="subtitles" srcLang="en" label="English" />
</video>
```

this give the following warning
`Resource interpreted as TextTrack but transferred with MIME type text/plain`

and the subtitles doesn't show

But after thinking about it it would be better to play the video file with the native media player if I am not mistaken. How to do so? using node child_process spawn? or is there an electron way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you can open a video player by using node's child_process spawn, but you need to somehow find what is the default video player and also take care of different operating systems.

On the other hand electron's way is much better. Using [shell.openItem](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenitemfullpath) electron will open the given file in the desktop's default manner. Also you could use [shell.openExternal](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/shell#shellopenexternalurl-options) to have the same experience regarding what your file path would be (url / filesystem path)